# How to select specific orders sets by its last value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

For my dataframe:

```
V1    V2   V3   V4   V5
1      1    1    1    0
1      1    1    0    1
0      1    1    0    1
1      0    0    0    0
```

I have written this code:

```
[{f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in d.items()} for d in df_train.iloc[:,:-1].to_dict('records')]
```

It gives me those ordered sets:

```
[{'V1:1', 'V2:1', 'V3:1', 'V4:1', 'V5:0'},
{'V1:1', 'V2:1', 'V3:1', 'V4:0', 'V5:1'},
{'V1:0', 'V2:1', 'V3:1', 'V4:0', 'V5:1'},
{'V1:1', 'V2:0', 'V3:0', 'V4:0', 'V5:0'}]
```

How can i get only those set orders with last value (value of V5) equal to 1? So i want to get this:

```
[{'V1:1', 'V2:1', 'V3:1', 'V4:0', 'V5:1'},
{'V1:0', 'V2:1', 'V3:1', 'V4:0', 'V5:1'}]
```

This didn't work:

```
[{f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in d.items()} for d in df_train.iloc[:,:-1].to_dict('records') if d[-1] == 1]
```

Comment: What is the data type of value? Are the `int` or `str` ?

Comment: @HirushaFernando i added dataframe example

Answer (score 0):

I made it with 2 for loop, I hope it helps

```
for a in List:
    N=list(a)
    for b in N:
        if b.startswith("V5"):
            if "1" in str(b):
                print(a)
```

Secondly, if you don't convert your data into a set format. You can use a simple BooleanMask, like in the picture.:)

(If your values are strings in your data frame, like in your set, you can just do the same but just with  Data[Data["V5"]=="1"]

[image]